# Common helpers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

Are there any plugins or tutorials available for common helpers which provide list of helpers ?

Like,

current_action?
current_controller?

I know it's depends on the project but still there should be some helpers which we can use in most of the projects.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are.

You current controller action name can be accessed by  `controller.action_name`

and current controller name by  `controller.controller_name`

Comment: I know these methods. I am asking about the other methods like this. Which we can use in most of the projects.

Comment: Not really You have to dig through the api. Try using  controller.internal_methods, controller.action_methods to find these